# Does CollectionAssociation.include? checks if record exists in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been reading Rails 3 Way and was checking the behavior of `CollectionAssociation.include?`

As per description in the book:

> Checks to see if the supplied record exists in the association
>   collection and that it still     exists in the underlying database
>   table.

I make couple of tests to check if DB is checked but looks like it is not checking.

```
> book = Book.first
=> #<Book id: 1, title: "Programming Ruby"...
> last_chapter = book.chapters.last
=> #<Chapter id: 2, title: "Chapter 2", book_id: 1, 
> b.chapters.include?(last_chapter)
=> true 
> last_chapter.destroy
  DELETE FROM "chapters" WHERE "chapters"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]
=> #<Chapter id: 2, title: "Chapter 2", book_id: 1, 
> b.chapters.include?(last_chapter)
=> true         
> book.chapters.reload
=> [#<Chapter id: 1, title: "Chapter 1", book_id: 1,...]
> b.chapters.include?(last_chapter)
=> false
```

I checked source code and found a line `load_target if options[:finder_sql]` which seems loads the record conditionally.

Do you have any idea when DB will get accessed to check if record is exists in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses both lazy loading and memoization.

This means that `b.chapters` does not load any chapters until you first call the getter.

Afterwards, destroying the chapter does not change the `include?` test, because of memoization. Rails does not reload what chapters are in the book. Thus, it will not know that the chapter no longer exists in the book.

Note that `include?` (defined on `Enumerable`/`Array` objects, but not implemented directly on the `ActiveRelation` object) will automatically cause Rails to cast the `ActiveRelation` object `book.chapters` to an array. Thus, `include?` will first get the array of chapters, then check if the chapter is included in the array.

Calling `reload` explicitly (on any `ActiveRecord` object) forces rails to reload that particular object, so that the caching of the chapters in the book is thrown away, and the actual chapters are reloaded.

- You cannot turn off memoization, except by calling `reload` everywhere you need it to reload.
- You can tell Rails to eager-load instead of lazy-load, by using `includes`, eg. `book = Book.includes(:chapters).first`. This means that Rails will load all the chapters at the same time as it loads the book(s).

To delete a chapter, while ensuring that `book.chapters` is up-to-date, you can call `books.chapters.delete(book.chapters.last)` or `books.chapter_ids.delete(book.chapter_ids.last)`. Using this method, Rails will not need to query the database again to know it is no longer in the collection.

Comment: thanks for insightful answer. It really helped a lot to understand many things.

Comment: But questions remains in which scenario the `include?` method hit the DB?

Comment: `include?` (or any other method that acts on an array) hits the DB if and only if the `chapters` have not already been loaded. `chapters` is not loaded until you call it the first time due to lazy loading. When I said "when you first call the getter", I meant, call `book.chapters`, which is a method which "gets" the chapters.

Comment: if the collection is not loaded it runs a db query that only checks for the existence of the object, not one that loads the entire collection (Similar to size that will do select count(*) if the collection isn't loaded)

Comment: Oh yes, that is the case. However, if the collection is already loaded, it just uses the array. However `last_chapter = book.chapters.last` loads the collection array already. So Rails uses the array in this case.